# What is the instantiation order in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form where in its Load method I set a couple of properties based upon a parameter list I receive in forms constructor.
When I tried to use one of those form's properties in one control on the form Ive got the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

So I found that at the time of using that form's property in that control's Event method the specific property is null. 
That go me thinking that the form's Load method is actually executed after all controls are instantiated, but I am not sure about it and I did not find anything relevant upon searching the net.

Comment: Show us the code

Comment: did you put your code _before_ `InitializeComponent();` ? - Please post your code.

Comment: Maybe you have another constructor which didn't execute `InitializeComponent();`. Please provide more information, also the code might be more helpful

Comment: Check on [Windows Forms Events Lifecycle](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mamta_m/windows-forms-events-lifecycle/) & [Order of Events in Windows Forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/86faxx0d(v=vs.110).aspx) => Use **Shown** to make sure everything is instatiated correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the form constructor is called. Within it, the `InitializeComponent` method calls all the constructors of the controls on the form (and those controls in turn may call other constructors of their own). The `Load` **event** fires when the form is first being shown, which is much later.

So under normal circumstances, fields you assign in the `Load` event handler will *not* be available in the constructor of the form or the controls on the form.

If you need to set something that needs to be accessible by the constructors of child controls, you either need to control the lifetime of these controls manually (rather than using the designer), or you need to assign that *before* the `InitializeComponent` method is called. Note that you must not use any of the controls before `InitializeComponent`, since they're still `null` at that point.

Comment: This explains it. Thanks.

Comment: @ZedMcJack Note that there's no magic involved. If you *find all references* to your `Load` event handler, you'll see that even that is actually assigned in the `InitializeComponent` handler. The invocation of load is a bit more hidden, since it has a lot to do with how the whole window system works on Windows, but it suffices to say that it depends on the window message loop, which doesn't run when your code runs (think the `Application.Run` that doesn't get to execute until your `new Form()` returns; and for non-main forms, until the event that caused them to be created returns).